# mod_rewrite: RewriteCond special HTTP/?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

recently I stumbled upon a mod_rewrite code snippet for Joomla which contains a RewriteCond that I do not fully understand.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}>s ^(443>(s)|[0-9]+>s)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http%2://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The second condition restricts to */index.php, but what does "HTTP/" at the end of the line?

Thanks

metaphor

Answer (score 0):

The `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable is the first line of an HTTP request, which looks something like this:

```
GET /index.php HTTP/1.1
```

Broken down, it's more or less the "METHOD" (GET/POST/HEAD/etc), the URI (/index.php, /foo/bar.php?something, etc), and the HTTP version (HTTP/1.1, HTTP/1.0).

The `HTTP/` isn't really needed at the end, since the existence of the space after `\.php` means the end of the request URI.

Comment: Jon, thanks for clarification.
So basically HTTP/ stands for "end of request"?

Comment: @metaphor_set It's the end of the first line, the rest of the request are headers that's not part of the variable. But HTTP requests can also be "short", where it is ends at the URI, with no version *or any headers*.